# How do you programmatically update a date field?

Tags: sitecore-forms, fieldtype

I try to set field in template of type "Date" programmatically,

```
string postedValue = GetValue(formSubmitContext.Fields.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.Equals(fieldName)));
DateField dateField = newItem.Fields[fieldName];
var ss  = Sitecore.DateUtil.ToIsoDate(DateTime.Parse(postedValue));
dateField.Value = ss;
```

When I debug the field is set with ISO value but in Sitecore the field is empty.
any idea ??

Answer (score 4):

You don't set the field value, you set the field.

```
newItem.Editing.BeginEdit();

string postedValue = GetValue(formSubmitContext.Fields.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.Equals(fieldName)));
var ss  = Sitecore.DateUtil.ToIsoDate(DateTime.Parse(postedValue));
newItem[fieldName] = ss; 

newItem.Editing.EndEdit();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use this construct:

```
item.Editing.BeginEdit();
make your changes
item.Editing.EndEdit();
```

or use the Editingcontext

```
using(new EditContext(item))
{
    item["FieldName"] = "A new value";
}
```

keep in mind there is also BulkEdititngContext(if you dont want to exp editor to reload)

Comment: His question is specifically about date field. Please update your answer for dates. This is just anything.

Comment: @Chris Auer: Regardless that the OP asked about "date field", his apparent problem, from his description, is that he doesn't know how to edit any kind of field. Ghodrat correctly surmised this and responded to his actual apparent problem.

Comment: I am pretty sure the title says "How do you programmatically update a date field?". Not much gray area for you to read into.

Answer (score -1):

You can update field as per sample code here we are using Editing class.

**Note:** Don't use EditContext if you have multiple operations and anyone failed then also it partially save data.Where Editing class will work just like a **transaction**, so if any operation will fail it'll rollback all operations.

```
Item item;
item.Editing.BeginEdit();
{
    //update field value ex- date value
    item["FieldA"] = "";    
}
item.Editing.EndEdit();
```

Comment: EditContext is considered to be a method you should no longer use. https://kamsar.net/index.php/2017/01/EditContext-Considered-Harmful/

Comment: That is right, if multiple operation we have to use Editing class.

Comment: @Michael West , I have updated answer as you suggested.